# Rabbit proofing gap in gate

Tags: walls, gates, gate-post

I have a gap between the wall and gate which allows rabbits to get into the backyard. My objective is to rabbit proof this gap.

I've considered pulling the gate closer to the wall with the threads on the hinges. That just moves the gap to the center.

My best idea at the moment is to epoxy some wire mesh to that gap. If you look carefully at the image you can see some residue from some duck tape that I used previously to seal the gap with some shade cloth. This worked for around a year until the duck tape came off. So I'm looking for a more permanent solution.

Although I think that my idea of wire mesh and epoxy will work I've found that 100% of the time that I've posted my idea to DIY that someone has answered with a better idea.

EDIT to answer questions:

The gate consists of 2 parts. There's an identical hinge on the other side.

The gate only needs to swing towards the position where the photo was taken from.

The gap is 1.75 inches wide. The black painted frame to the gate is metal. You can see another metal pole against the wall. The wall itself is block.

[image]

Comment: Move the gap to the center the attach a board on one side only on the inside that overlaps the gap.  Doing that on the hinged side won't work, because then the gate can't open, but on the latch side it can be done.

Comment: A big question here is: "Does the gate need to swing both ways?". The answer to that will determine what options exist for making a permanent fix.

Comment: How wide is that gap? What is the material on the outside edge; would it accept screws?

Comment: Question edited to add answers to the comments.